# Viber photo sync

Tags: facebook, viber-messenger

My husband is having an issue with photos being sent to him via the Viber app are being synced and posted directly to his Facebook page! How does he stop this?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is done by Facebook's photo sync, not Viber. See Facebook's [help page](https://www.facebook.com/help/274634689307648) on how to disable photo syncing.

## How do I turn photo syncing off?

### Android

1. Open the Facebook app and tap the top left main menu in your sidebar
   [image]
2. Scroll to the bottom and select Settings > App Settings
   [image]
3. Choose Don't sync my photos
   [image]

Comment: I find that Facebook seems to be more aggressive in what photos it syncs. It seems to find images that Google+ Photos and Dropbox don't, for instance.

Comment: Hmmm...I could not find this option of "not syncing photos" on FB as you described it. Do I have to access FB from a pc to see this option?

Comment: @Jtc see updated answer for better instructions.